# Fuzz JSON with Peach

Tags: json, rest, flask, fuzzing

I have made a small REST based webservice in Flask by reading http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask  and now I wanted to fuzz the JSON using Peach framework. I know it's uses a pit file(XML) for fuzzing but my small brain is not able to make the pit file that can serve my purpose. I googled a lot for peach pit file but all goes in vain. 
I need a pit file or anyone can tell how to create a pit file for fuzzing payload.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice tutorial about peach available [there](http://rockfishsec.blogspot.ch/2014/01/fuzzing-vulnserver-with-peach-3.html).

Several elements need to be defined:

- a data model describing the format of the data you want to send.
- a state model describing the behavior of the fuzzer.
- an agent runnning and monitoring the applications under fuzzing.
- a test bringing all definitions together.

Here is an example of a Peach Pit file from the tutorial.

```
<Peach xmlns="http://peachfuzzer.com/2012/Peach" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://peachfuzzer.com/2012/Peach ../peach.xsd">
  <DataModel name="DataHTER">
    <String value="HTER " mutable="false" token="true"/>
    <String value=""/>
    <String value="\r\n" mutable="false" token="true"/>
  </DataModel>
  <StateModel name="StateHTER" initialState="Initial">
    <State name="Initial">
      <Action type="input" ><DataModel ref="DataResponse"/></Action>
      <Action type="output"><DataModel ref="DataHTER"/></Action>
      <Action type="input" ><DataModel ref="DataResponse"/></Action>
    </State>
  </StateModel>
  <DataModel name="DataResponse">
    <String value=""/>
  </DataModel>
  <Agent name="RemoteAgent" location="tcp://127.0.0.1:9001">
  <!-- Run and attach windbg to a vulnerable server. -->
    <Monitor class="WindowsDebugger">
      <Param name="CommandLine" value="C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\vulnserver\vulnserver.exe"/>
      <Param name="WinDbgPath" value="C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)" />
    </Monitor>
  </Agent>
  <Test name="TestHTER">
    <Agent ref="RemoteAgent"/>
    <StateModel ref="StateHTER"/>
    <Publisher class="TcpClient">
      <Param name="Host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
      <Param name="Port" value="9999"/>
    </Publisher>
    <Logger class="File">
      <Param name="Path" value="Logs"/>
    </Logger>
  </Test>
```

If you want to use a JSON data model, you can follow the [recommendation of one of the peach architect](https://forums.peachfuzzer.com/showthread.php?111-JSON-File-Fuzzing).

1)Define a data model corresponding to the JSON.

**JSON Object**

```
{
  "name":"John Smith",
  "address":{
    "address1":"555 Main St.",
    "city":"Seattle"
  }
}
```

**Data model**

```
<DataModel>
  <String name="name" value="John Smith" />
  <Block name="address">
    <String name="address1" value="555 Main St." />
    <String name="city" value="Seattle" />
  </Block>
</DataModel>
```

You then have to write your own custom publisher in C#. Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2014/01/creating-custom-peach-fuzzer-publishers.html) for this.

Comment: The question is how to fuzz the json part ?

Comment: @Ortomala Lokni, did you find how to fuzz json. I know that there is pyjfuzz but it is not supported by python3